Embed Accessibility view does not allow user to click the controls
I have few documents in SharePoint and I would like to show them as embed in my react web page. And also I want to show the page in accessibility mode. In this mode it shows paging , zooming and other controls at the top of the iframe. How ever, user cannot click the controls. I see that there is a div element covering the entire toolbar, the div is coming from the SharePoint document viewer I frame, and I does not have any control of it because it is a separate domain.
Is there any other solution to this issue ?

Can we add my web site host name as a trusted domain so that I can access the inner html and  remove the div using css ?
Is there any other way to show these controls without accessibility mode ?


